# Why does this Elixir script only print the first message?

Tags: elixir

I have the following code:

```
parent = self()

spawn_link(fn ->
  send(parent, "foo")
  send(parent, "bar")
end)

receive do
    x -> IO.puts x
end
```

When I run this script "foo" gets printed, but not "bar". Am I missing something fundamental about Elixir processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `receive` expression only handles one message. The usual way to handle this is to put the `receive` expression inside a function and after it's done processing a message make it call itself again recursively.

```
defmodule Receiver do
  def loop do
    receive do
      :exit -> :ok # don't recurse
      x ->
        IO.puts x
        loop
    end
  end
end

parent = self()

spawn_link(fn ->
  send(parent, "foo")
  send(parent, "bar")
  send(parent, :exit)
end)

Receiver.loop
```

prints

```
foo
bar
```

You can also `receive` `n` messages using:

```
defmodule Receiver do
  def loop(0), do: :ok
  def loop(n) do
    receive do
      x ->
        IO.puts x
        loop(n - 1)
    end
  end
end

parent = self()

spawn_link(fn ->
  send(parent, "foo")
  send(parent, "bar")
end)

Receiver.loop(2)
```

This also prints

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: Thank you! I can now let the bruise on my forehead start healing!